# Feedback and suggestions on Functioning of Drupal Answers?

Tags: support

I have been on Drupal Answers for several months. During this experience, I found many things which needs attention regarding functionality of Drupal answers, mostly are suggestions for good.  Where can I post that?

Does any feedback/suggestion & further improvement feature there where user can post that? OR we need to add on  Drupal Answers Meta?

Answer (score 3):

You post them as individual questions here, on Meta.